# Git extract commits from a branch into a new one

Tags: git

I have the following tree:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P <- br-3
  ^     ^
br-1   br-2
```

And I'd like to have all commits from br-1 & br-3, but none from br-2 in the middle:

```
    C-D-E <- br-2
   /
A-B-F-G-H-I-J-K-L-M-N-O-P <- br-3
  ^
br-1
```

Number of commits in br-3 (that are not on br-2) is too big to be cherry picking E,F,G,H... on top of B.

I'd expect this to be something that's possible through rebase, but didn't find anyone doing the same as I'm trying to.

Comment: Git rebase --onto br-1 br-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is as simple as:

```
git rebase --onto br-1 br-2 br-3
```

Check the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for `git rebase`.

Your question is the second example for option `--onto` in the documentation (it just uses different names for the branches) :-)

Comment: It's a bit confusing for me whether having br-1, br-2 or br-3 as the current branch matters for this command.

Comment: Using this version of the command, the current branch does not matter at all. Before anything else, `git rebase` will do `git checkout br-3`. If you omit `br-3` from the command then `br-3` should already be the current `HEAD`. Of course, in order for the `rebase` to succeed, the working tree must be clean (no added/modified/removed files, nothing staged for commit).